# How to remove key from properties keeping the original order?

Tags: java, properties

I have to use a properties file and I'm interested in keeping the order of keys after removing one of them using `remove()`method. Is there any way to do this?

Example: I have 5 entries on properties and I want to remove the 3rd keeping the order (1,2,4,5).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Post your persistence code, please.

Comment: The class Properties extends Hashtable, which cannot guarantee a lasting order. You might however override `public Enumeration<?> propertyNames()` and first sort the names. Or keep your own collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).

It will insert the order of insertion and even if you remove 3rd it will keep the required order.

Answer (score 0):

First of all load it as:

```
  Properties properties = new Properties();
  properties.load(reader);
```

then use `remove()` method.

```
  properties.remove(key);
```

Also refer the link : [Properties:java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html)